# How to upgrade or downgrade the Kernel in Ubuntu (to any stable or testing release)

Tags: upgrade, kernel, bug-reporting, debugging

When I report a bug I may be asked to "try out the latest upstream Kernel", how do I do that?

I see a lot of version specific answers to this question here on ask ubuntu, what are the general instructions?

Answer (score 1):

Here are generic instructions that work on any version of Ubuntu:

There's a lag between when a Kernel is released, and when it's available packaged in  Ubuntu updates.  To add a new Kernel to the list of boot options, get the packages from here:

```
http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/
```

You'll need to match your Ubuntu version, and your 32 or 64 bit system type.
Download those files to your `/tmp` partition using `wget` or something similar, and run:

```
sudo dpkg -i linux-*.deb
```

Optionally, to remove an old Kernel, find the right version number then run:

```
sudo apt-get purge linux-image-YYYYYY*
```

Once a Kernel is installed it will be available to select at boot time.  Be sure to leave at least one Kernel at all times, preferably leave two (the one your system was originally supplied with, and your current version).

Comment: If that answer works for you, you can accept it by hitting the checkmark, even if it's an answer to your own question.