# Why wasn't my kernel upgraded when I upgraded the system?

Tags: package-management

I recently upgrade from 14.10 to ubuntu 15.04 and I was expected also the kernel to be upgraded from 3.16 to 3.19, but this wasn't happened!
Why this problem? can I do manually upgrade of kernel?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/379033/how-to-upgrade-or-downgrade-the-kernel-in-ubuntu-to-any-stable-or-testing-relea/379034#379034

Comment: Edit your post and add the output of `apt-cache policy linux-image-generic` and `lsb_release -sc`.

Comment: Same thing is happening for me. Release is `vivid`.  output from apt-cache is: `linux-image-generic:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 3.19.0.16.15
  Version table:
     3.19.0.16.15 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-security/main amd64 Packages
     3.19.0.15.14 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid/main amd64 Packages
`

Answer (score 6):

Open a terminal and type:

`$ sudo apt-get install linux-generic`

Restart and you should see on Grub that the kernel version should 3.19

Comment: This will not work if grub is set to use the last working version of the kernel, in which case one might have the latest kernel, but being unable to boot from it.