# Issue with vboxadd setup and I think my Ubuntu may be running the wrong kernal

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, kernel, 15.04, virtualbox

I recently upgraded Ubuntu from 14.04 to 15.04 and from my understanding vivid uses l*inux 3.19.0-16-generic* kernal. However, when I use:

```
uname -r
```

It says I'm using *3.16.0-46-generic*.

This is a problem because when I am trying to execute:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/vboxadd setup
```

it fails. The log reveals that kernal headers for kernal 3.16.0-46-generic cannot be found. After I tried to install these headers using

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

and

```
sudo aptitude install linux-headers-3.16.0-46-generic
```

I get:

> Package 'linux-headers-3.16.0-46-generic' has no installation
>   candidate.

I've tried adding sources from the trusty-updates' linux-headers pages, but that doesn't work. Any idea on what is the issue and how to fix it?

Comment: since you are running Vivid Vervet I wouldn't expect trusty-updates to work. I have a tendency to stick with the LTS versions. That being said you could take a look at /var/log/vboxadd-install.log for some clarity. What version of virtualbox are you using? My version of 15.04 (on a test system) is up to date using 3.19.0.26-generic have you tried to apt-get update and apt-get upgrade?

Comment: @ElderGeek 
I'm using VirtualBox 5.
/var/log/vboxadd-install.log says:
Error! Your kernal headers for kernel 3.16.0-46-generic cannot be found. Please install the linux-headers-3.16.0-46-generic package, or use the --kernelsourcedir option to tell DKMS where it's located
Failed to install using DKMS, attempting to install without /tmp/vbox.0/Makefile.include.header:97: *** Error: unable to find the sources of your current Linux kernel. Specify KERN_DIR=<directory> and run Make again. Stop.
Creating user for the Guest additions.
Creating udev rule for the Guest Additions kernel module.

Comment: @ElderGeek

I have tried apt-get update and apt-get upgrade but they were no use. To me it seems like there may be a bug preventing my upgrade to 15.04 receiving the right kernel. But I'm inexperienced with this so I may be wrong.

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/617065/why-wasnt-my-kernel-upgraded-when-i-upgraded-the-system

Comment: You may need to update grub.

Comment: @ElderGeek Ah, okay. Well sudo apt-get install linux-generic seems to be working. I noticed that this may not work if grub is set to use the last working version of Kernel. Is this something I should be worried about?

Comment: if your uname -r output is still not correct then you need to resolve that.

Comment: @ElderGeek It worked! Thanks for your help, mate. Wasn't expecting it so quickly.

Comment: Your welcome and Welcome to askubuntu! , I've written the working solution up as an answer. If it's complete please upvote/accept it so that others with the same issue can find a solution. If not, please write a more detailed answer for the same reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Begin by updating your kernel to the latest version as shown [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/617065/why-wasnt-my-kernel-upgraded-when-i-upgraded-the-system)

Check to insure that your kernel version is correct for your version of Ubuntu with the command `uname -r` if not, issue the command `sudo update-grub` and reboot into the most current kernel. Try your vboxadd command again.